# Auto Sort different ranges

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, sorting

I have a google sheet that I would like to sort different ranges by the 2nd column in each range.
Example:

```
A B C D E F G  
p 7 1 h 9 1   
q 6 2 j 3 2  
g 9 3 p 7 3
```

I need the range A:C sorted by B and the range E:G sorted by F.
When I write the script, only the first set of data sorts. Here is the script I have so far based on my current spreadsheet:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  var range = sheet.getRange("A3:C450");

 // Sorts by the values in column 2 (B)
 range.sort({column: 2, ascending: true});

function onEdit(e) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
   var range = sheet.getRange("D3:F450");

 // Sorts by the values in column 5 (E)
 range.sort({column: 5, ascending: true});
  }
}
```

How can I get it to run both of thse?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it natively with `QUERY` and `ARRAY{}`

In you example, try this :

```
={QUERY(A1:C3,"SELECT * order by B asc"),D1:D3,QUERY(E1:G3,"SELECT * order by F asc")}
```

Replace `asc` with `desc` according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  oE1(e);
  oE2();
 }

function oE1(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  var range = sheet.getRange("A3:C450");
  // Sorts by the values in column 2 (B)
  range.sort({column: 2, ascending: true});
 }

function oE2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  var range = sheet.getRange("D3:F450");
  // Sorts by the values in column 5 (E)
  range.sort({column: 5, ascending: true});
 }
```